# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') - Blockchain JS

Tags: javascript, typeerror, blockchain

I keep getting an error stating that it cannot read the return in getLatestBlock. I literally followed a YouTube video step - by - step. It worked for him I don't understand what i'm doing wrong?

The video was released in 2017 - have there been changes to JS that i'm unaware of? Thanks all.

```
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

class Block {
  constructor(index, timestamp, data, previousHash = "") {
    this.index = index;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.data = data;
    this.previousHash = previousHash;
    this.hash = this.calculateHash();
  }

  // Hash identifies the block
  calculateHash() {
    return SHA256(
      this.index +
        this.previousHash +
        this.timestamp +
        JSON.stringify(this.data)
    ).toString();
  }
}

class Blockchain {
  contstructor() {
    this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
  }

  createGenesisBlock() {
    return new Block(0, "01/01/2017", "Genesis block", "0");
  }

  getLatestBlock() {
    this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
  }

  addBlock(newBlock) {
    newBlock.previousHash = this.getLatestBlock().hash;
    newBlock.hash = newBlock.calculateHash();
    this.chain.push(newBlock);
  }
}

let savejeeCoin = new Blockchain();
savejeeCoin.addBlock(new Block(1, "10/07/2017", { amount: 4 }));
savejeeCoin.addBlock(new Block(2, "12/07/2017", { amount: 10 }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(savejeeCoin, null, 4));
```

Comment: `getLatestBlock` does not return anything so that is one bug. `return this.chain[t......`

Comment: Wow thanks man, I literally missed that completely! Thank you! : ) Will give that a go now!

Comment: `calculateHash` doesn't write to the istance...this whole class should be refactored a bit...The whole class could be using only `static` methods...there's no point of creating an instance to just call calculateHash externally (IMHO)

Comment: @Sampgun Thanks for the comments Sam. Could you provide any suggestions on refactoring?

Comment: @SherozeMohammed I would move the block hash inside the block (without savingg the previous)...let the blockchain being only a chain of blocks...And the index should be dinamic

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's a typo in your `Blockchain` class:
`contstructor` should be `constructor`. That's why you don't get your stuff initialized and get the error.

I would refactor the thing a bit:

1. Allowing to set initial data, using defaults
2. Move the current hash inside the block, I don't like it very much that each block should contain (and maintain) the previous hash (and half the required memory this way).
3. Make members private so they can be written only on Block creation
4. Add getters to read values after creation
5. Reuse addBlock to create the initial block
6. Don't pass the date as string, but use timestamp
7. Save the current timestamp at creation (prevents possible frauds)
8. Avoid the data object, because it's too arbitrary. Use another class if you need more data, in the meantime I only saved the amount as number.
9. Concat params differently with a separator (this could be avoided, but it was good for my eyes )
10. Don't set properties from outside (like hash) after the block constructor is called. Everything (as said before) is set on creation and should be immutable!

Hope this helps...It looks more OOP to me.

Cheers

```js
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

class Block {
  get amount() {
    return this._amount;
  }

  get hash() {
    return this._hash;
  }

  get index() {
    return this._index;
  }

  get timestamp() {
    return this._timestamp;
  }

  constructor(index, amount, prevHash = '') {
    // make all props private so they can be written only once
    this._index = index;
    this._timestamp = +new Date();
    this._amount = amount;
    this._hash = SHA256(
      `${this.index}-${prevHash}-${this.timestamp}-${this.amount}`
    ).toString();
  }
}

class BlockChain {
  get chain() {
    return this._chain;
  }

  constructor() {
    this._chain = [];
    this.addBlock(0, 'Genesis block');
  }

  getCurrentHash() {
    this.chain[this.chain.length - 1].hash;
  }

  addBlock(amount, prevHash = this.getCurrentHash()) {
    this.chain.push(new Block(this.chain.length - 1, amount, prevHash));
  }
}

let savejeeCoin = new Blockchain();
savejeeCoin.addBlock(4);
savejeeCoin.addBlock(10);

console.log(JSON.stringify(savejeeCoin, null, 4));
```

Blitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-k2im49) where I implemented private members (#) and a build fn to print single blocks and the chain...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time bro. The code definitely is more readable and better structured than I initially followed. After implenting these changes, I'm not sure why but I still get the error:  'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')'

Comment: @SherozeMohammed wait a sec...I'm preparing a Blitz with the code...

Comment: @SherozeMohammed there is a typo in your constructor. See above. That's why you don't get your stuff initialized and get the error.

Comment: *Facepalm*.  Literally that was the issue. Corrected the typo and the whole process runs fine now. Much appreciated Sam and Epascarello!!!